# How to reduce BARCODE FONT in barcode module?

Tags: theming

I am using Barcode module to generate barcode i have downloaded that module from drupal.org modules,i am able to reduce the rectangle lines of barcode but under the rectangles lines i have serial number like "**123456**" i cant able to reduce the size of it,I need to reduce the size of serial number.any suggestions.Thanks in advance

Comment: did you try using css?

Comment: @  No Sssweat - thanks for your response,exactly i cant able to found where i need to change.

Comment: highlight the numbers, right click with your mouse and select inspect element. Then look for a class name or id name.

Comment: @  No Sssweat - there is no css file in barcode module.

Comment: Use your theme .css file and put the css code there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31494/discussion-between-dine-and-no-sssweat).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your theme css file, in `/sites/all/themes/yourtheme/css`

```
.barcode { font-size: 10px; }
```